# Movie about teenagers and werewolves on a school trip

Tags: story-identification, movie, werewolf

I want to find the name of a movie that involved a group of teenage kids going on a bus trip during the winter season. There was one kid that turns into a wolf at night. I think they were going to pass a tunnel when the wolf kid disappeared. I think the end scene was where the wolf was rescued by a girl since he fought another group of wolves, who I think were also part of the school trip. I think the wolf kid had feelings for the girl, but she didn't like him back. I think this movie was around the 90's and I think the kid was around 10-13 years old. The girl and the kid used to walk to school together. And kid used to turn to a wolf just at night.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds similar to episode 1x5 of Wolfblood but that is from 2012 and not the 90s and both the boy and the girl are werewolves.

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2335086/plotsummary?ref_=tt_ov_pl

Comment: Similarly, probably not the episode of Teen Wolf that involves wolves attacking the bus on a trip.